# Expected Number of Proofreading Rounds Before All Typos are Discovered

Tags: probability

Here is a probability question I had in mind. I think I have a solution, but can't figure out a simpler expression (if one exists):

*Suppose there are K typos in a paper.
Each time I read through the paper, I notice each typo independently with probability p.
If I notice a typo, I fix it immediately (so that in subsequent versions, the typo no longer exists).
What is the expected number of times I have to read the paper before all mistakes are fixed?*

Letting $T$ denote the random variable equal to the number of rounds before I discover all typos in a paper and $T_k$ denote the random variable equal to the number of rounds before I discover typo $k$, I figured that
$$ Pr(T_k \leq t)=1-Pr(T_k>t)=1-(1-p)^t.$$
So, this implies
$$Pr(T > t)=1-Pr(T \leq t)=1-Pr(T_k \leq t)^K=1-[1-(1-p)^t]^K,$$and since $T$ is a non-negative integer-valued random variable,$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}Pr(T>t)=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}1-[1-(1-p)^t]^K.$$
However, I am having trouble simplifying this series(I think it converges), and was wondering whether someone either knows how to simplify it, or can arrive at a simpler expression by thinking about this problem from another perspective.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Thanks whuber for your hint! I managed to arrive at the following expression:
$$ \mathbb{E}[T] = - \sum_{k=1}^{K} {K \choose k} \frac{(-1)^k}{1-(1-p)^k}$$
I was wondering whether there is some way to further simplify it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: expand the terms in the sum using the Binomial Theorem, switch the order of summation, and remember how to sum a geometric series.

Comment: It does not appear to simplify any further in general.